# Which word is most common in everyday language for an electrical outlet - "socket", "outlet", or "plug"?

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

In everyday language, which standalone word denominates it best?
"Socket", "Outlet" or "Plug"?

[image: image of a wall socket/outlet/plug]

Comment: A potentially relevant question asked years ago on ELU (before ELL was created): [*Difference between “socket” and “outlet”*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42259/difference-between-socket-and-outlet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picture is of a [wall] **outlet or socket**. Those are common,everyday terms used by everyone.

The **plug is what goes into the outlet or socket**. You plug a lamp into an outlet or socket (aka power point in the UK) with a plug.

**Plugs have pins**. Sockets or outlets have holes into which you plug the gizmo with the pins sticking out of it.

These are everyday terms used for these common electrical items. **You do not need to use the word power or electrical in everyday speech**.

In any case, a power or electrical outlet is the same thing as an electrical or power socket.

Comment: Ok, so referring to a "wall outlet" / "wall socket" (as in the picture) by using the term "socket" for instance is correct?

Comment: If you're finding that people are asking you to clarify something you thought you made clear, you probably didn't make it as clear as you thought you did. You may want to consider stating it more explicitly. For example *You can use either "wall outlet" or "wall socket" to describe the picture. The word "wall" is optional - you don't need to add it unless you're distinguishing the socket in the wall from a socket in some other location.* The punctuation you're using to express all of that may not be clear to a non-native speaker.

Comment: Socket is more used in Britain: outlet is common in US usage.